# Get last available entry

Tags: sql, mariadb, groupwise-maximum

I am using `10.1.39-MariaDB - mariadb.org binary` and I have the following table:

```
| id    | date                | ticker | close     | createdAt           | updatedAt           | CompanyId |
|-------|---------------------|--------|-----------|---------------------|---------------------|-----------|
| 39869 | 2019-09-18 00:00:00 | AAPL   | 221.96160 | 2019-09-18 19:25:30 | 2019-09-18 19:25:30 | 238       |
| 39870 | 2019-09-17 00:00:00 | AAPL   | 220.70000 | 2019-09-18 19:25:30 | 2019-09-18 19:25:30 | 238       |
| 39871 | 2019-09-16 00:00:00 | AAPL   | 219.90000 | 2019-09-18 19:25:30 | 2019-09-18 19:25:30 | 238       |
| 39872 | 2019-09-13 00:00:00 | AAPL   | 218.75000 | 2019-09-18 19:25:30 | 2019-09-18 19:25:30 | 238       |
| 39873 | 2019-09-12 00:00:00 | AAPL   | 223.09000 | 2019-09-18 19:25:30 | 2019-09-18 19:25:30 | 238       |
```

Furthermore, I have the following query to get for the last day the top 5 `daily_returns`:

```
SELECT *
FROM (SELECT prices.*,
             CAST((`close` - @old_close) / @old_close AS DECIMAL(20, 10)) AS daily_return,
             @old_close := `close`
      FROM prices,
           (SELECT @old_close := 0 AS) AS t
      ORDER BY ticker,
              `date` ASC) AS tt
WHERE DATE >= DATE(NOW()) - INTERVAL 1 DAY
ORDER BY `date` DESC,
         daily_return DESC
LIMIT 5
```

However, on Monday I only get empty results back as no prices have been inputed to the db as markets stand still.

How to overcome this weekend problem and take the *last* price that was posted in the db?

Comment: In your query, I don't see a reference to current date or yesterday day. So, unless I am reading it wrong, it should not have any issues with weekends

Comment: @MadhurBhaiya Sorry my fault. I copied the query that I was using for debugging. Find above the query that breaks!

Comment: Why not just increase the date range from -interval 1 day to -interval 2 day. You anyways are getting data in descending order on date. This will handle weekend case. And on a normal weekday, it will get yesterday's data only

Comment: What version are you using?  If it has `LAG()`, then use that to find the "previous day".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1 of the methods is using CASE statements -

```
SELECT *
FROM (SELECT prices.*,
             CAST((`close` - @old_close) / @old_close AS DECIMAL(20, 10)) AS daily_return,
             @old_close := `close`
      FROM prices,
           (SELECT @old_close := 0 AS) AS t
      ORDER BY ticker,
              `date` ASC) AS tt
WHERE DATE >= CASE WHEN DAYNAME(NOW()) = 'Monday' THEN DATE(NOW()) - INTERVAL 3 DAY  -- OR 2 DAY, DEPENDS UPON YOUR REQUIREMENT
                   ELSE DATE(NOW()) - INTERVAL 1 DAY END
ORDER BY `date` DESC,
         daily_return DESC
LIMIT 5
```

Comment: @RickJames, The best methods to handle such situations is to have a holiday table and increase a date which are present on that table. Since OP doesn't have such situations i have not included that on the answer.